# Strange character appearing at start of string

Tags: c, string, character

I am taking different transistor data from a file. The program stores that in a structure. It then prompts for an input from the user. User enters 5 different values, eg 12 0.03 100 320 65 and then the program takes these values and compares it to the data from the file and sees if any transistors would be suitable for the parameters you have entered. 
The program then prompts the user again, and this repeats until the letter q is entered, which ends the program.

The problem I'm having - and I've been trawling the internet for hours trying to find a solution but none of them have worked - is that any input after the first set isn't accepted. So it looks like this.

Please input: Voltage Current Power Frequency Gain
15 0.1 200 100 80
15 0.1 200 100 80
ALL RELEVANT TRANSISTORS
Please input: Voltage Current Power Frequency Gain
20 0.3 100 150 40
?1 2 3 4 5

The question mark is always a strange character. In the past few hours it has been a ? in a diamond, the letter P, and a small square with 0010 in it. Everything I have found on the internet says this should work. What am I missing?

Here's my input function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 15
struct input{
    int volt, power, freq, gain;
    float amp;
};
struct input inputs[MAX_IN];

int CHK =1, number=0;

int input_function1()
{
    const char check[3] = {'\0'};
    int i;
    const char inp[30] = {'\0'};



    printf("Please input: Voltage Current Power Frequency Gain\n");

    fgets(inp, 30, stdin);
    puts(inp); //Prints out the string to see if the input has been correctly accepted                              
    ungetc(inp, stdin);

    sscanf(inp, "%s", &check);
    if(check[0]!='q' && check[1]!='q' && check[2]!='q')
    {

    sscanf(inp, "%d %f %d %d %d", &inputs[number].volt, &inputs[number].amp, 
    &inputs[number].power, &inputs[number].freq, &inputs[number].gain);

    }

}
```

Below is how I am calling the function. check_function is the function which checks the input transistor against the database.

```
while(CHK==1)   
{
    input_function1();

    check_function();
    ++number;

}
```

Comment: please always check the return value of `sscanf`

Comment: @SeekAddo what does that actually mean? :S

Comment: `sscanf` returns the number of characters read, so is always advisable to check if the required number of inputs were read.

Comment: hey is your compiler not giving you warnings with your `const char inp[30]` `[-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types-discards-qualifiers]` just remove the const

Comment: @SeekAddo yeah correct number of inputs and that doesn't make a difference the strange character is still there

Comment: what do you think this is doing `ungetc(inp, stdin);`

Comment: I have no idea
That was what I was told to use to get the input to work for just one of them

Comment: i never said that was going to solve your problem. I gave a comment of advise.

Comment: Using functions you do not know, gets you nowhere: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/ungetc.3.html

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  to start, the macro `MAX_IN` is not defined within the posted code.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the "%s" input/conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, to avoid any buffer overflow.  Such overflow results in undefined behavior and can/will lead to a seg fault event.  I.E.  if( 1 != sscanf(inp, "%2s", &check) ) { perror( "scanf failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code:  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line

Comment: do not `#include` header files that the code is not using.  This poor programming practice will 'bite you' when some header file is modified and the code is not actually using the contents of that header file.  Suggest removing the `#include` for `string.h` and `math.h`

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings. (for `gcc` at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a little example which fixes some stuff of your current snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define MAX 15

struct input {
    int volt, power, freq, gain;
    float amp;
};
struct input inputs[MAX];

int fill_input(int index) {
    char check[4];
    char inp[30];

    printf("Please input: Voltage Current Power Frequency Gain\n");

    fgets(inp, 30, stdin);
    puts(inp);
    sscanf(inp, "%s", &check);

    if (strcmp(check, "qqq") == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    sscanf(inp, "%d %f %d %d %d", &inputs[index].volt, &inputs[index].amp,
           &inputs[index].power, &inputs[index].freq, &inputs[index].gain);

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int index = 0;

    while (1 && index < MAX) {
        if (!fill_input(index)) break;
        index++;
    }

    printf("End");
    getch();
}
```

The goal of the above snippet is to help you to move on.

Few notes for you to consider though:

- Try to avoid global variables as much as possible
- The current provided version is far away from being optimal, think why is that and don't just copy paste other's code, try to figure out what a good function is all about. The most important lesson for you here should be how to code proper functions
- The errors in your snippet are related to arguments not matching properly the datatypes, for instance, take a look to the fgets [docs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm), you can see the first argument is `char*`, you were using `const char*`, datatypes should match
- Try to refactor the function till is good one and learn as much as possible from each refactoring
- Have fun coding! <--- most important one

Comment: Thank you! That works! I will try my best to improve my skills

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a `const char` array like this:

```
const char test[30] = {'\0'};
```

and that actually creates a string/array that is not editable and the terminating 0 that should mark the end of a string is the only character in this array. Also this zero is being set at the `test[0]`.